# Serialize/deserialize System.RuntimeType

Tags: c#, serialization, types

I've got a List of Types that I need to save to file and read it after. 
I use `DataContractSerializer` but I get an exception during deserialization:

> Can't find constructor with arguments (SerializationInfo,
>   StreamingContext) in ISerializable "System.RuntimeType".

I've added `System.RuntimeType` as a known type to my serializer, but it didn't help.

Here's code of my two methods

```
public static void SaveTypes(List<Type> types, string fileName)
{
    Type rt = types[0].GetType();

    List<Type> knownTypes = new List<Type>() { rt }; //I get a List with System.RuntimeType item here
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Type>), knownTypes);
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    Stream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(fs, settings))
        serializer.WriteObject(xw, types);
}
```

Serialization seems to work fine, and the output file is ok, but problem starts on deserializing:

```
    public static object LoadTypes(string fileName)
    {
        Stream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] data = new byte[file.Length];
        file.Read(data, 0, (int)file.Length);

        Type rt = file.GetType();
        List<Type> knownTypes = new List<Type>() { rt.GetType() };
        DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Type>), knownTypes);

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return deserializer.ReadObject(stream); //exception here
    }
```

Is there any way to go through this? Or maybe there's some other way to store types?

Comment: You should be serializing the **data**, not the implementation. A `Type` is 100% about implementation. Frankly, it is simply the wrong way to go, and it would be a disservice to help you go further down that dark path. IMO.

Comment: I do serialize the data, but it contains user defined types that i can't get access to. So when i deserialize them i need to know that types. I thought the only way to get access to them is to store them in a file.

Answer (score 3):

Marc Gravell is right, you probably should be serializing the data and not the types.

But for some reason, if you really want to serialize the types themselves, then you shouldn't serialize the Type object (pretty sure it's not serailizable).  Anyway, serialize `Type.FullName` instead.  When you load the Types, use `Type.Load`

```
public static void SaveTypes(IEnumerable<Type> types, string filename)
{
    using (var fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]))
            .Serialize(fs, types.Select(t => t.FullName).ToArray())
}

public static IEnumerable<Type> LoadTypes(string filename)
{
    using (var fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)
    {
        var typeNames = (string[])
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]))
            .Deserialize(fs);

        return typeNames.Select(t => Type.Load(t));
    }
}
```

*Note:* When working with any `Stream` (or really any `IDisposable`) you have to either call the `Dispose` method or use the `using` statement (as I did above).  This ensures that the `IDisposable` is properly cleaned up (ie releases File System handles).

Comment: For some reason I can't find Type.Load method. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: He probably meant to serialize [`Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Type.FullName`, to load the type using [`Type.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than the nonexistent `Type.Load`, and should have probably suggested to use [`IDataContractSurrogate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than manually substituting the values before/after serialization.